# Is there way to style tags with "similar" ids in CSS?

Tags: css

I have an XML file created through a proprietary graphics package that, broadly, is formatted something like this:

```
<content>
<RootWidget attr="X1">
  <Widget attr="X2">
    <Foo attr="X3"></Foo>
    <Foo attr="X4"></Foo>
    <Foo attr="X5">
       <Bar attr="X6"></Bar>
       <Bar attr="X7"></Bar>
    </Foo>
  </Widget>
  <Widget attr="X8">
     <Foo attr="X9"></Foo>
  </Widget>
</RootWidget>
</content>
```

NOTE: Here, "attr" is some special attributes in the XML describing the position/color/fonts/etc of whatever widget we're talking about.

I also have a compiled program written in what I presume to be Java/Jetty voodoo that will convert the above XML into a HTML file like so:

```
<div id="root">
  <div id="root.RootWidget" style="Y1">
    <div id="root.RootWidget.Widget" style="Y2">
      <div id="root.RootWidget.Widget.Foo" style="Y3"></div> 
      <div id="root.RootWidget.Widget.Foo1" style="Y4"></div>
      <div id="root.RootWidget.Widget.Foo2" style="Y5">
        <div id="root.RootWidget.Widget.Foo2.Bar" style="Y6"></div>
        <div id="root.RootWidget.Widget.Foo2.Bar1" style="Y7"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div id="root.RootWidget.Widget1" style="Y8">
    <div id="root.RootWidget.Widget1.Foo" style="Y9"></Y9>
  </div>
<div>
```

Basically, the converter takes all the widgets in the XML file, assigns them a unique ID based on their position in the DOM, and converts all the proprietary formatting attributes (X1,X2...) into an in-line "style" attribute within the HTML (Y1, Y2...)

I also have a CSS file that I can access and modify, which styles the final HTML page.  I want to be able to use this style-sheet to apply styling to e.g. all Widget/Widget1/Widget2 (etc) children of RootWidget parents or all Foo/Foo1/Foo2 (etc) children of Widget/Widget1/Widget2 (etc) parents or all Bar/Bar1/Bar2 (etc) children of Widget/Widget1/Widget2 (etc) parents but not Foo/Foo1/Foo2 (etc) parents, and so on.  How can I do this with the HTML format that comes out of my software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based of the given structure I would choose the `suffix` attribute selector `[id$="value"]` (since they all look the same in the beginning) and the `contain` selector `div[id*="value"]`.

```css
div[id$='RootWidget'] div {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 0px 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
div[id$="Foo"] {
  background: green;  
}
div[id*="Foo2Bar"] {
  background: red;  
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div id="rootRootWidget" style="Y1">
    <div id="rootRootWidgetWidget" style="Y2">
      <div id="rootRootWidgetWidgetFoo" style="Y3">1</div> 
      <div id="rootRootWidgetWidgetFoo1" style="Y4">2</div>
      <div id="rootRootWidgetWidgetFoo2" style="Y5">
        <div id="rootRootWidgetWidgetFoo2Bar" style="Y6">3</div>
        <div id="rootRootWidgetWidgetFoo2Bar1" style="Y7">4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="rootRootWidgetWidget1" style="Y8">
      <div id="rootRootWidgetWidget1Foo" style="Y9">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you say "mess up," does that mean there's no way to make the selectors work without removing the dots?  I have no way to remove the dots, they're automatically generated by a black-box program I don't have source access to.

Comment: @Frank: No, what I meant to say was that some browsers might not work as expected, but I see now, when I tested again in IE11, it works ... must have been something else when I tried first time, updated and removed that suggestion in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yep!

Just use the `element[attribute^=value]` tag.

In your case, I think the selector would be

```
.root-widget > div[id^='Widget']
```

Comment: I think your selector doesn't work.  For one, the HTML document has no classes, so `.root-widget` isn't going to select anything.  For another, the `attribute^=value` translates to "`attribute` starts with `value`", which is doesn't match the `id` in the HTML, which would start with (e.g.) `"root.RootWidget.Widget"`.  Am I misunderstanding CSS here?